# python: badly behaving dict inside a function- erroneous TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary, typeerror

I have dicts that I need to clean, e.g.

```
dict = {
  'sensor1': [list of numbers from sensor 1 pertaining to measurements on different days],
  'sensor2': [list of numbers from from sensor 2 pertaining to measurements from different days], 
  etc. }
```

Some days have bad values, and I would like to generate a new dict with the all the sensor values from that bad day to be erased by using an upper limit on the values of one of the keys:

```
def clean_high(dict_name,key_string,limit):
    '''clean all the keys to eliminate the bad values from the arrays'''
    new_dict = dict_name
    for key in new_dict: new_dict[key] = new_dict[key][new_dict[key_string]<limit]
    return new_dict
```

If I run all the lines separately in IPython, it works.  The bad days are eliminated, and the good ones are kept. These are both type `numpy.ndarray`:  `new_dict[key]` and `new_dict[key][new_dict[key_string]<limit]`

But, when I run `clean_high()`, I get the error:

> TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

What?

Inside of `clean_high()`, the type for `new_dict[key]` is a string, not an array.
Why would the type change? Is there a better way to modify my dictionary?

Comment: Can you provide a working example with some sample data along with the full error trace?

Comment: What parameters are you passing to `clean_high(...)`?  Also, do the arrays for each sensor have the same shape (each sensor took a measurement on the same days)?  If a day is bad in one sensor, you want to remove that day's value from all sensors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not modify a dictionary while iterating over it. According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict): "Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries". Instead, create a new dictionary and modify it while iterating over the old one.

```
def clean_high(dict_name,key_string,limit):
    '''clean all the keys to eliminate the bad values from the arrays'''
    new_dict = {}
    for key in dict_name:
        new_dict[key] = dict_name[key][dict_name[key_string]<limit]
    return new_dict
```